# Dynamically assigning different data type to v8::local<v8::value>argv[1]

Tags: c++, v8, node.js-addon

How to assign two data type to `v8::Local<v8::Value>argv[1]` based on incoming data(int,string,bool) type as below.

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[1];
 if(Isint)
{
  argv[0] = Nan::New<v8::Number>(intValue).ToLocalChecked();
}
if(IsString)
{
  argv[0] = Nan::New<v8::String>(stringValue);
 }
if(IsBool){
  argv[0] = Nan::New<v8::Boolean>(boolValue);
}
```

Note :  Final argv[0] will hold only one value either int,string or bool based on **if check** performed above.

Above implementation throw run time error as **terminated SIGSEGV**. Please help me to fix this. This my first attemp on V8.

Can argv[0] assigned as above?

Comment: What are `IsInt`, `IsString`, `IsBool`, `intvalue`, `stringValue` and `boolValue`? Presumably you've defined those somewhere in your code but how do you know that your error isn't in that bit of your code? More to the point how to we know?

Comment: IsInt IsString and IsBool is funtion which return o and 1.  example if IsInt return 1 . The i need to assign argv[0] with integer value This integer value is global and assignment is done during int.

Comment: OK but your error could be in `IsString` for instance. So post the code for `IsString`. Don't just post the code where you think the error is (you might be wrong). Post all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above code has no any run time error. The error is  coming form any of IsInt, IsString, IsBool.